# PHP Commands to USB Modem

Tags: php, command, usb, modem, at-command

Please what is the AT commands in PHP compatible with Huawei USB Modem ?

i need to use these commands in script then i can send sms using the Huawei USB Modem.

thanks

Comment: It may be possible to talk to a modem from PHP to some extent, but you want to use a command-line tool to do it. Look up how to communicate with your modem using a tool for your OS

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you need to do is to open up the serial port with PHP.  There is a class for doing this:  http://code.google.com/p/php-serial/

Once open, it is as simple as this:

```
$serial->sendMessage("AT+CMGS=\"+1231231234\"\nHello");
```

Obviously, the AT commands can vary from device to device, so you will need to find out the commands for your specific device.

Comment: +1 although under Windows you can just hope your message was sent, the Windows implementation is write only in its present form.

Comment: @fvu, that is correct.  You don't know of a better serial class by chance, do you?  The only other method I can think of (outside of `exec()`), would be to invoke a COM object.

Comment: see my response for a radically different approach - issue #1 in the issue list proposes a solution to the writeonly problem that's so simple it's almost incredible...  Not sure what's going on there.

Answer (score 2):

A saner approach would be to delegate SMS management to a specialized software, because in my experience there's more to do to manage SMS sends than just throwing a couple of bytes to a modem

- network availability checks and the corresponding retries to optimize your delivery rate
- capability to receive SMS'es
- multipart messages
- routing
- ...

I suggest the most excellent [SMSTools](http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/) it's a server software compatible with Linux and Windows, it talks with your application via regular ASCII files in specific directories (in, out, failed, ...) and has a host of other advanced functions.

To send a basic sms with default options you just have to create a text file like this one

```
To: 155512345

Hello, this is the text of the SMS
```

in the out-spool directory, on Linux that's `/var/spool/sms/outgoing` unless you reconfigure that path.

Best of all it's free and open source.